# Difference between contract address and contract instance on ethernaut

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

I'm in [ethernaut](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/), on the second level: Fallback.
I don't understand the difference between the level address and the instance address. Which of these refers to the contract they show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance address refers to the contract that you are interacting with.

If you go to your console you can confirm this by typing:

```
contract.address
```

Which will match the instance address that is shown.

Comment: Thanks, but then what is the level address?

Comment: When you click "Get New Instance", you are calling the ethernaut.sol contract to deploy a new contract to the goerli network for you to interact with. This newly deployed contract's address is the instance address. The ethernaut.sol contract needs the level address to tell it how to deploy your instance contract (i.e. Which level does it need to deploy a contract for?).